# Combinação de uma lista numérica com limitador (Python)

Tags: python, lista, combinações

Estou gerando todas as combinações possíveis dentro de uma lista, mas não encontrei nenhum que suprisse todas as minhas necessidades, sendo elas:

- Resultado em formato de lista;
- Listas com itens repetidos são válidas;
- Listas completamente iguais não são válidas;
- Deve haver um limitador de tamanho máximo para geração da lista;
- O somatório dos itens da lista não pode ser maior que tamax;
- O tempo de execução do código é importante;

Fiz o código abaixo, mas **gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais refinada/pythônica de escrever esse mesmo código.**

OBS: **Usei limitadores para diminuir o número de iterações do gerador**, pois eu tinha que fazer combinações com uma lista de 30 números, e sem os limitadores o código nunca terminava de rodar.

```
import numpy as np
from math import floor
from itertools import product

tamax = 12 #valor máximo da soma dos itens na lista
tamin = tamax * 0.95 #valor mínimo da soma dos itens na lista
tamanhos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] = lista para combinações
tamanhos.sort()
limites = [] #armazena os limites para cada número de iterações
iteracoes = [] #armazena o número máximo de iterações que os elementos da lista vão gerar se combinados. É pareado com a lista limites
check = [] #usado como checagem para adicionar itens na lista limites
tamcomb = [] #armazena todas as combinações de tamanhos
comb = () #combinação do gerador aleatório


def sumall(tupla): #retorna o somatório do itens da tupla gerada
  tam = len(tupla)
  lista1 = list(tupla[0:tam])
  return np.sum(lista1)


def cresc(tupla): #transforma a tupla em uma lista em ordem crescente
  tam = len(tupla)
  lista = list(tupla[0:tam])
  lista.sort()
  return lista

for i in tamanhos:
  iteracao = floor(((tamax-i)/min(tamanhos))+1) #retorna o número máximo de iterações que podem ocorrer nas combinações entre os itens da lista
  if iteracao not in iteracoes: #adicionar o número à lista iteracoes
    iteracoes.append(iteracao)
  for j in range(0, (max(iteracoes)+1)): #adiciona na lista limites o tamanho referente ao número de iterações calculado
    if j == iteracao:
      if iteracao not in check:
        limites.append(i)
        check.append(iteracao)
limites.sort(reverse=True)
iteracoes.sort()

print("iteracoes = ", iteracoes)
print("limites = ", limites)

for i in range(1, (max(iteracoes)+1))):
  limite = 0
  for j in iteracoes:
    if i <= j:
      if limites[iteracoes.index(j)] > limite:
        limite = limites[iteracoes.index(j)]
  tamanhos_validos = [tamanho for tamanho in tamanhos if tamanho <= limite] # gera a lista com os tamanhos que serão utilizados de acordo com o número de iterações
  gerador = product(tamanhos_validos, repeat=i) # repeat é utilizado para especificar o numero de item que as combinações irão possuir
  for comb in gerador: #gera as combinações com base no tamax e tamin
    if tamax >= sumall(comb) >= tamin:
      comb = cresc(comb)
      if comb not in tamcomb: #se a combinação ainda não existe em tambcom, é adicionada na lista
        tamcomb.append(comb)
print("combinações validas = "tamcomb)
```

Output:

```
iteracoes = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
limites = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
combinações validas = [[2, 10], [3, 9], [4, 8], [5, 7], [6, 6], [1, 1, 10], [1, 2, 9], [1, 3, 8], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 6], [2, 2, 8], [2, 3, 7], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 5], [3, 3, 6], [3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 9], [1, 1, 2, 8], [1, 1, 3, 7], [1, 1, 4, 6], [1, 1, 5, 5], [1, 2, 2, 7], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2, 6], [2, 2, 3, 5], [2, 2, 4, 4], [2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 8], [1, 1, 1, 2, 7], [1, 1, 1, 3, 6], [1, 1, 1, 4, 5], [1, 1, 2, 2, 6], [1, 1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 1, 2, 4, 4], [1, 1, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 2, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Esse código demorou cerca de 9s para rodar no Google Colab.

Comment: Não sei se entendi exatamente todos os critérios, mas enfim, uma sugestão: https://ideone.com/0NXpxz

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, atualizei pra tentar explicar melhor, espero ter conseguido. Já atualizei algumas parte de acordo com o que eu vi no seu código, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra simplificar bastante esse código.

Pelo que entendi, a ideia é buscar todas as combinações, mas a ordem dos elementos parece não importar. Ou seja, se já tiver `[2, 10]` nos resultados, então não precisa ter `[10, 2]`. Portanto, uma opção melhor é trocar `itertools.product` por [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

Só isso já diminui significativamente a quantidade de possibilidades a serem testadas. No caso, sua lista tem 10 elementos (os números de 1 a 10), então `product(lista, repeat=n)` resulta em 10<sup>n</sup> elementos diferentes para serem testados. Já `combinations_with_replacement(lista, n)` resulta em `(9 + n)! / n! / 9!`. Por exemplo, para `n` igual a 6, `product` gera 1 milhão de possibilidades (inclusive as repetidas que não são necessárias, como já mencionado), enquanto `combinations_with_replacement` gera apenas 5005 combinações (ou seja, quase 200 vezes menos possibilidades). Para `n` igual a 10, a diferença é maior ainda: 10 bilhões de `product` versus 92378 de `combinations_with_replacement` (cerca de 100 mil vezes menos possibilidades).

Com isso você já ganha um bom tempo. E como os valores já estão ordenados, as combinações também estarão (primeiro ele gera de 1 a 10, depois `(1, 1)`, `(1, 2)`, etc, depois `(2, 1)`, `(2, 2)` e assim por diante). Assim, não precisa ficar ordenando as tuplas, o que significa mais um ganho de tempo.

Enfim, ficaria assim:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # valores usados nas combinações
valores.sort() # não precisaria nesse caso, pois vc já criou a lista ordenada
tamax = 12 # valor máximo da soma dos itens na lista
tamin = tamax * 0.95 # valor mínimo da soma dos itens na lista

# calcula as iteracoes
iteracoes = []
etc... (confesso que não entendi essa parte, mas usei o seu código, e a mesma lista abaixo)


results = []
for i in range(1, max(iteracoes) + 1):
    for comb in combinations_with_replacement(valores, i):
        if tamin <= sum(comb) <= tamax:
            results.append(list(comb)) # transforma a tupla em lista e adiciona nos resultados

print(results)
```

Repare que não precisa de uma função para calcular a soma, pois o Python já tem isso pronto: [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) recebe qualquer iterável, inclusive uma tupla (não precisa transformá-la em lista, ganhando mais tempo ainda).

E nos resultados, para converter a tupla em lista, basta usar `list` passando a tupla direto (criar os *slices*, como você fez com `[0:tam]`, além de gastar mais tempo, é desnecessário nesse caso em que você quer pegar todos os elementos - isso faria sentido se você quisesse pegar apenas um pedaço da tupla). E como agora eu não retorno mais as combinações repetidas, nem preciso verificar se já existe na lista de resultados.

[Rodei no Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eOd0o90uhXhJxiFE6FbxUf0Yl1fmDlPI) e demorou cerca de 0,3 segundos.

---

Também fiz um teste com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
def com_permutations():
    # seu código com permutations...

def com_combinations():
    # meu código usando combinations_with_replacement...

from timeit import timeit

# executa 1 vez cada teste
params = { 'number' : 1, 'globals': globals() }
# imprime os tempos em segundos
print(timeit('com_permutations()', **params))
print(timeit('com_combinations()', **params))
```

Os tempos podem variar de uma máquina para outra, na minha foram (em segundos):

```
5.775390355000127
0.13096024300102727
```

Como pode ver, um ganho significativo (de 5,7 para 0,13 segundos, cerca de 40 vezes mais rápido).